# Java String.split() on comma followed by non-whitespace

Tags: java, regex, split

I'm parsing a dataset which annoyingly decided to comma-delimit items in a TSV (PharmaGKB pathways, I'm looking at you), but allow commas in each logical element.

Basically, comma-followed-by-space means no delimit, while comma followed by character means new element.

> "This is one, element,two element, three element"

Should be:

- This is one, element
- two element
- three element

I have the regex `a.split(",\\S+");`, which splits fine **but** it removes the first character after every split.

- This is one, element
- wo element
- hree element

Regex is like going to the dentist for me, help is much appreciated.

Comment: To anyone reading this -- please note that the given example is incorrect. The actual output should be "This is one, element" "two element, three element". There is a space after the comma between "two element" and "three element" and thus it should not be treated as a delimiter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Positive lookaheads:

```
a.split(",(?=\\S)");
```