# Alternative way to split a comma-delimited string in java where

Tags: java, split

So I'm trying to split a string that is delimited using a comma:

```
Record: Jason,Smith,124 Will Street, CA

Expected Result of split:
Jason
Smith
124 Will Street, CA
```

However, if the use the following code I'm getting the expected result:

```
String str = "Jason,Smith,124 Will Street, CA";
String[] record= str.split(",");

Actual Result:
Jason
Smith
12 Will Street
 CA
```

Is there a way to get the Expected Result?

We tried a surrounding the string in double-quotation mark but the result is the same

```
Result:
"Jason"
"Smith"
"24 Will Street
 CA"
```

Comment: `split` accepts a second parameter, to `limit` the number of splits.

Comment: split also takes a regex expression, so try using comma followed by non white space see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20315673/java-string-split-on-comma-followed-by-non-whitespace  `str.split(",(?=\\S)");`

Comment: To complete luk2302's comment: [split javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,int))